# Alternative clients and the Bitcoin API

Tags: client, alternatives, json-rpc, api

Which of the alternative clients support any/some/all of the standard [API calls](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)? I am looking for a possible alternative client to replace Bitcoind on my server.

Answer (score 4):

The [Blockchain.info API](http://blockchain.info/api/json_rpc_api) includes Bitcoind as a JSON webservice. It's pretty cool.